# ASP.NET MVC with Plesk

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hosting, plesk

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application that I'm trying to publish to Plesk, but I get a 500.21 Internal Error each time about a bad module.

In general, I'm not sure how to work with Plesk and ASP.NET MVC, this is my first time deploying to a hosting service and I haven't found much documentation on it. Could anyone point me to some helpful resources?? Or copy/paste some good instructions on how to do this? It seems anything that I do find is outdated..

Comment: I've never used plesk but there are numerous tutorials on how to publish your web application to the web.  If you want to be able to deploy a .net application, the place where you publish it needs to have the asp.net hosting libraries and a runtime to be able to run your code.  If you are talking about .net framework 4.6-4.8 code (older MVC), same thing applies, but you'll need the .net framework (not .net core) runtime.  Right-click on your project in the VS solution explorer and click publish to see some of your options.

Comment: I've tried to look into installing a runtime, but my plesk manager doesn't have an option for tools and installations. I'm wondering if that is something my hosting service (GoDaddy) controls?

Comment: Yeah most likely it's controlled by GoDaddy.  I have never tried deploying an app there but I would look into azure.  There are free trials and it's pretty easy to get your app on the web really easily. I can try playing around with plesk though and providing an answer

Comment: Thank you, that would be awesome! I'm going to get on the phone with GoDaddy tech as well and see what they can do for me.

Comment: If you are deploying .Net Core application try setting Out-of-process hosting model

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/out-of-process-hosting?view=aspnetcore-5.0#out-of-process-hosting-model

Comment: Looks like plesk doesn't support .NET apps at all currently.  I did see that they have a docker extension - you might be able to try deploying your .NET app as a docker app and publishing to dockerhub - pulling into plesk somehow.  I have not been able to fully go through the deployment process though - I would consider using another tool instead of plesk, unless you have a hard-requirement for plesk.

Comment: @TateW You can upload your files using FTP or WebDeploy to your server. To publish using WebDeploy, you can read https://windowswebhostingreview.com/how-to-publish-using-web-deploy-with-plesk-control-panel/. I also use Plesk panel here.

Comment: I figured it out! Looks like plesk doesn't support .NET core, but it does support regular .NET. Thanks for all the help everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that Plesk Onyx doesn't support .Net core (or at least GoDaddy won't enable the drivers to support it). I had to transfer it all over to .Net 5 and that solved the problem!

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I'm also use Plesk here at Asphostportal and Plesk doesn't support for .net core. But your hosting provider can setup .net core manually via server.